# consistency between ranked lists

Tags: machine-learning, computational-statistics, order-statistics

I have 5 features used in 3 models to estimate an outcome.
Then I checked their significance in the 3 models to see which features are more significant.
I got 3 lists of significant features, one for each model as below sorted from the most significant one to less significant one.

```
M1  M2  M3
--  --  --
F1  F2  F1
F3  F3  F4
F2  F1  F3
F4  F5  F2
F5  F4  F5
```

Is there any statistical method to calculate and check the consistency between these 3 lists?
I checked and different methods have been proposed such s Friedman test and Kendall's correlation.
But I do not know which one is more suitable.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want an aggregated ranking? Or do you just want an answer to the question "are these rankings similar?"

Comment: @MONODA43, I want to see exactly what you said. Are these rankings similar ?

Comment: Kendall's tau is definitely the more common statistic to check.

Comment: Thanks @MONODA43